# How do i use python list inside a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium

How do i use a python list inside a javascript code?

```
stream_id = 4000

# add stream sources list
a_file = open("C:/Users/Unknown/Documents/Selenium/stream_source.txt", "r")

stream_sources_list = []
for line in a_file:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  stream_source_line_list = stripped_line.split()
  stream_sources_list.append(stream_source_line_list)

a_file.close()

print("stream_sources:", len(stream_sources_list))

    while listposition < len(stream_sources_list):

        # navigate
        driver.get("http://192.168.94.128:25500/stream.php?id={}".format(stream_id))

        driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementById('stream_source').setAttribute('value', '{stream_sources_list[listposition]}');")

        stream_id = stream_id + 1
        listposition = listposition + 1
```

this is the part that doesn't work: '{stream_sources_list[listposition]}'

```
driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementById('stream_source').setAttribute('value', '{stream_sources_list[listposition]}');")
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback for this error? And the code where you actually call this `driver.execute_script()` function? What you shared appears to only include you reading items from a file into a list and then printing the length of that list.

Comment: for some reason i'm unable to post the full code, it says your post is mostly code, so i tried minimizing the code and going already to where the problem is.

Comment: Perhaps if you add a little verbiage describing your problem in more detail you'll be able to do it. The full traceback would make this easier to understand.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is, i have a list, and inside this list there are items, i go to a link and log in, then there are inputs, and instead of typing, i set the value of each input with the items of the list there, it's a loop that will do this for every item of the list.

Comment: Got to have that code and a traceback. This current question isn't reproducible, it's unclear what the actual error is without a traceback, and if the problem is in the way you're using `selenium` it's not diagnosable without seeing the code you wrote.

Comment: Updated, do you think now it's clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use node.js child process
child_process.spawn():

here is an example
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-python-script-node-js-using-child-process-spawn-method/#:~:text=Child%20Process%20allows%20us%20to,to%20spawn%20child%20process%20asynchronously](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-python-script-node-js-using-child-process-spawn-method/#:%7E:text=Child%20Process%20allows%20us%20to,to%20spawn%20child%20process%20asynchronously).